# Strong class type for mapping root array in JSON response

Tags: c#, json

Client application I don't have much control over has an established pattern for making calls to a particular API. Drilling down into the existing methods I find it's using `System.Net.Http.Json` and calling `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TResponse>(content)`, which I believe just takes a a target type `TResponse` and [tries to convert the passed JSON string accordingly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-6.0).

I've gotten this to work great in every scenario except one - where the response from the API is an unlabeled array:

```
[{value: "stuff1"}, {value: "stuff2"}, {value: "stuff3"}]
```

Every other JSON response object looks something like this:

```
{
    data: ["blah", "blah", "blah"]
    value: 15, 
    prop: "whatever"
}
```

And example working Type:

```
[JsonPropertyName("data")]
public IList<string> Data {get;set}

[JsonPropertyName("value")]
public int Value {get;set}

[JsonPropertyName("prop")]
public string Prop {get;set}
```

But my problem response doesn't have any named keys, it's just an array... so how do I create a `Type` for an array with no key?

Answer (score 0):

Two days of head scratching and I figure it out moments after posting a question:

Just pass in a list of type as the `TResponse` type:

```
 IList<MyCustomType>
```